# jQuery render HTML as plain text w/ toggle (toggle is working fine, but cannot covert the HTML to text)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is my current code. And it is working fine, but I need the .code class element to display as plain text and not render as HTML.

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function( ) {
 $('.code').hide();
 $('.codeLink').toggle(
    function() {    
   $(this).next('.code').fadeIn();
     $(this).addClass('close');
    },
    function() {
      $(this).next('.code').fadeOut();
        $(this).removeClass('close');
  }
); // end toggle
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<a class="codeLink" style="margin-bottom: 10px; display: block;" href="#">Get The   Code</a>
<div class="code"><a class="benefitsQandA" href="#">Get an Instant Quote &amp;    Apply</a></div>
```

This section of the .code class should display on the screen exactly like this (in other words not rendered as HTML just as text):

```
<a class="benefitsQandA" href="#">Get an Instant Quote &amp; Apply</a>
```

Comment: Is it only the HTML rendering that's the problem? I don't exactly see how the toggling is involved.

Comment: It's preferable to use a "null javascript" href over a hash ("#"), like this: href="javascript://"

Comment: Toggling is NOT involved, but it was part of the broader scope to give the full code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
$(".code").text($(".code").html());
```

of course, if you are doing that to multiple divs, you would need to use .each:

```
$(".code").each(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: It's worth noting that .html() doesn't always return the exact code entered since it's a representation of the DOM. see: http://api.jquery.com/html/ "Some browsers may not return HTML that exactly replicates the HTML source in an original document"

Comment: JustJohn, it seems to be working fine in later versions of WebKit.

Comment: It's probably fine in most of the modern browsers but if you have to be backwards compatible it's best to avoid calls that behave differently across browsers.

Comment: Any idea how to maintain the formatting with jQuery as well? I can't find any methods that seem to address that.

Comment: maintain formatting, asing not changing to &lt; stuff? do the replace outside of the toggle rather than inside of it. it only needs to happen once, not every time you toggle.

Answer (score 3):

Use `$(".code").text($(".code").html())`

Comment: This works on the first attempt, but after the toggle and re-click close the code goes to character encoding like: &amp;lt;a class="benefitsQandA" href="#"&amp;gt;Get an Instant Quote &amp;amp;amp; Apply&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;

Comment: You seem to be looking for some sort of CSS trick to escape HTML characters, and AFAIK there isn't one. You need to actually replace the HTML with escaped HTML, and your other code will just have to account for that somehow.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to handle this is to escape the code you don't want the browser to render, like this:

```
<a class="codeLink" style="margin-bottom: 10px; display: block;" href="#">Get The Code</a>
<div class="code">&lt;a class="benefitsQandA" href="#"&gt;Get an Instant Quote &amp;amp; Apply&lt;/a&gt;</div>
```

If you don't then you aren't guaranteed the correct output from the browser since JQuery's .html() tag is a wrapper for .innerHTML (See http://api.jquery.com/html/) which doesn't always return the exact same markup that you use.

You can take a look at a tool like the one at http://accessify.com/tools-and-wizards/developer-tools/quick-escape/ to do the escaping for you.

Wikipedia also has a [reference of XML/HTML entity codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)

Answer (score 1):

Could you not do this from the server?

When the user hits the toggle button pass the html to the server, using php replace the < and > characters with `&lt;` and `&gt;` and return the html back to the page.

unless you are dealing with a very large amount of data this shouldn't take long to process. and this way you will get 100% exactly what the original markup is.

Comment: Why do it in PHP if Javascript is *at least* as powerful as a programming language? Like: `t.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;')`

Comment: php will not 'modify' your original source.. javascript _may_

Comment: come to think of it, unless the code is being input into a textarea or some other input element you will be using javascript to post it to the server.... hrmm.